# Uploading from AS3 to S3 using presigned url

Tags: actionscript-3, amazon-s3

I want to upload an image from flash directly from flash to S3. Request I need to make seems to need to be a PUT request which I don't think flash supports. Has anyone got flash to work with S3 using pre-signed urls? Have tried adding X-HTTP-Method-Override didn't seem to work. Thought there may be a way with sockets?

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLDotNetSDK.html

http://verveguy.blogspot.co.uk/2008/07/truth-about-flex-httpservice.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working using a library called **as3httpclient**

https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient

One of the test cases included in the source code is an upload to S3, so nice and easy :)

https://github.com/gabriel/as3httpclient/blob/master/test/s3/HttpsTest.as

UPDATE:

Things all worked smooth until the html page was on a webserver and then ran into problems with sandboxing which stopped everything working. It seems the library only works from AIR, not from html pages. In the end had to save using a post request and setting headers from flash. An example of flash code is here http://aws.amazon.com/code/1092.

Comment: could you repost the example flash code?  The link is broken, as I get an error, maybe put it on a gist?

Comment: @LilDwarf not checked it but maybe try this http://blog.adambalchunas.com/2011/03/storing-content-on-s3-from-flash.html